# SQL - Limit Time a Join Shows a Result

Tags: sql, join, subquery, limit

I have tried desperately to get this to work and I am stuck. Any help is appreciated! I have two tables. Table 1 is customers and table 2 is the location and qty of inventory. The issue is I need the number of times a bin is recommended to be limited by the quantity so once it's recommended the entire quantity it stops recommending that bin...This is what stumps me.

```
Table 1
Customer | Item | Qty
1 | Item1 | 2
1 | Item2 | 1
2 | Item1 | 1
3 | Item1 | 1
4 | Item1 | 1
5 | Item1 | 1
6 | Item1 | 1

Table 2
Item | Bin | Qty
Item1 | A1 | 1
Item1 | A84 | 2
Item1 | C32 | 2
Item1 | D01 | 1
```

Output would would stop recommending the first match once the times matched hits the qty count... I am completely stuck...

The output would look like
    Customer | Item | Bin
    1 | Item1 | A1
    1 | Item2 | A84
    2 | Item1 | A84
    3 | Item1 | C32
    4 | Item1 | C32
    5 | Item1 | D01
    6 | Item1 |  (since there is no other bin left)


The script so far with the help of Ponder is...

```
SELECT
    CUST.CUSTOMER, CUST.ITEM, BIN
FROM (
        SELECT 
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY CUSTOMER, ITEM ORDER BY CUSTOMER ASC, ITEM ASC) AS RN, 
            CUSTOMER, 
            ITEM 
        FROM CUSTOMERS 
    ) CUST
LEFT JOIN (
            SELECT 
                ITEM,
                BIN, 
                LAG(Q2, 1, 0) OVER (PARTITION BY ITEM, BIN ORDER BY ITEM ASC, BIN ASC) Q1, 
                Q2
            FROM (
                    SELECT
                        ITEM,
                        BIN,
                        SUM(QTY) OVER (PARTITION BY ITEM, BIN ORDER BY ITEM ASC, BIN ASC) Q2
                    FROM INVENTORY I
                    )
                ) INV ON Q1 < RN AND Q2 <= RN AND CUST.ITEM = INV.ITEM
```

Comment: Please show the results that you want.

Comment: Is this for an exercise or for a real program you're actually going to use?

Comment: Real program we want to use! Right now the query only gives all bins and staff is running around to the same bins as each other and it's problematic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Number rows in table customers. Make cumulative sum of quantities in table locations. Assign rows from customers to locations using left join and defined ranges. You did not specify what RDBM you use, so here is Oracle solution, but it uses standard functions which should work in most databases, or at least you can easily apply this logic:

```
select customer, item, bin
  from (select row_number() over (order by customer) as rn, customer, item 
          from customers)
  left join (
        select bin, lag(q2, 1, 0) over (order by bin) q1, q2 
          from (select bin, sum(qty) over (order by bin) q2 from locations))
    on q1 < rn and rn <= q2
```

**<sup>[dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=ab4a80844c1dc712b4b54aa414958eb2)</sup>**

Seems that `item` is not used to join rows (in your example you have no Item2 in locations). In case you need it, use `partition by` in analytic functions and use `item` in join condition.

Comment: Ponder, thank you for the solution. I am researching the PARTITION BY and the OVER functions I have never used them before so I am working on that. I added the script you provided so far linked to the tables.

Comment: **1)** Can you tell us which engine you use? Postgres, MySQL, Oracle, SQL Server? **2)** Do categories of items matter? Is item2 something different than item1 (like food and clothes) and it has to be searched separately? It is not clear from your examples. If yes, you need `partition by` and `a.item=b.item` in join. Like in this [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=1435c88ec6c1dd8ea740304b59933774). If not, above solution is enough.

Comment: My apologies! 1) It's an Oracle DB and I use Oracle SQL Developer for the queries that send the report out. 2) Categories of Item don't matter, it's just an inventory table of item numbers, the bin where the item is located and how many are in that bin. So when I joined on the item it shows multiple bins and everyone keeps overlapping and trying to get items from the same bins.

Comment: Ponder, thank you very much that is awesome! I have not dug heavily into analytical functions but clearly my skill set has massive room to grow. Time to hit the books on the Oracle Analytical functions!

Comment: Ponder, I revised the script to what is above, using the partition by. But, it repeats the Item for each customer...any idea where I went wrong? I neglected to also bring in the qty that the customer ordered...I failed to include that originally. Any help is appreciated while I attempt to learn these new analytic functions.

Comment: Please look at my both dbfiddles. This answer and first dbfiddle contains version where you do not need partitions. From what you said about items I understand that you don't need them. Second dbfiddle shows usage of partitions and corrected join where items are treated separately.

Comment: Ponder, terribly sorry, I did not see the second dbfiddle!